AzureDevops : Delivery plan in multiteams
I'm a beginner on AzureDevops.
I have created 2 teams, and I have only one area.
My iterations are built like this

Project

Iteration 1

Teams 1

Sprint 1
Sprint 2


Teams 2

Sprint 1
Sprint 2







I have created on delivery plan with my 2 teams on user story mode.
Bug each of my teams have all user stories (team 1 and team 2)
I think I'm making a mistake, but I don't know which one
Thanks for your help

the issue is caused by same area is assigned between different teams. I can reproduce the same on my side, to resolve the issue, please use different areas between teams, and update the existing work item area. I add the details below, thanks.


I have created on delivery plan with my 2 teams on user story mode. Bug each of my teams have all user stories (team 1 and team 2)

This is caused by that same area is used in both teams. While you can assign the same area path to more than one team, doing so can cause problems if two teams claim ownership over the same set of work items.
As mentioned on Delivery plan doc:

To fix the issue, please go to project settings -> Boards -> Team configuration -> Areas page, use different area path for different teams. You can change the default area so that new work items will have different area by default.

Edit the existing work items, fix the area path with different one then refresh the delivery plan.

